# Single clicking on a select in Firefox immediately causes the options dropdown to close

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, firefox, select, drop-down-menu

For some reason, and only in Firefox, a select box with multiple options will immediately disappear after single clicking on the select.

The contents of the select aren't being constantly rewritten, and there is only a event handler for change. And I'm basically using Bootstrap for styling.

Any thoughts on why this might be happening?

Comment: This has happened to me with a `select` inside a `label`. If you can't move your `select` out of the `label`, here's a quick and dirty hack that will keep your dropdown open: `<label onclick="return false;">`

Answer (score 4):

When I've seen this the issue was wrapping multiple `<select>` controls within the same `<label>`

Chrome seems to handle this issue fine, but Firefox tries to open the first `<select>` when any of the subsequent `<select>`s is clicked.

The solution is to either not wrap them in a `<label>`, or to wrap only the first select within the label.

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/lsirivong/jmeGv/

Answer (score 1):

Even tho this question is very old, I just stumbled upon it while searching for the same symptoms.

For some reasons Firefox closes select elements when drawing to a canvas element on the page. 
In my usecase I was able to workaround this by not updating the canvas while any select input is in focus:

```
if (jQuery('select:focus').length > 0) {
    return; //Skip rendering while select is in focus
}
```

Hope this helps somebody desperatly trying to figure out why their dropdowns close immediately.

Answer (score 0):

i experienced this same issue today and after painstakingly bisecting my code i found out that it was because of a `filter: brightness(1.4);` CSS property that was affecting the select element. i have no idea why this is difficult for Firefox, but hope this is useful information to someone.